# Can't see the correct result in a search query

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String a = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            a += params[i];
            if(params[i++] != null){
                a += "%20";
           }
        }
        url = new URL("mysite/search.php?q="+a);
```

I don't understand why if i write: 'The book'
I see these results: 'The book ...' , 'The table ...', 'The phone ...'.

The problem seems to be that this code works only with params[0], and can see only 'the ' or 'the' and can't see 'book'.

Comment: We can't see what you are passing to the AsyncTask's `execute` method. If you give `"The book"`, then `params` is only of length one

Comment: Also, you do not want `i++` within the loop. That wiil skip over elements within the `params`. If you would `Log` the value of `a`, you would see that

Comment: Please show how you call the execute method of the async task. If use used `execute("The book")`, then no, it is only `params[0]` and it equals `"The book"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are more characters than spaces that you need to url-encode.

I don't think you need to loop over anything, though. Java has classes that can do this.

```
String searchFor = URLEncoder.encode("the book", "utf-8"); // "the+book"
```

Note: depends on your search engine, but `+` and `%20` should be handled similarly.

So, assuming you are using `task.execute("the book")`, then just do

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String a = URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "utf-8");
    url = new URL("mysite/search.php?q="+a);
```

---

Though, I prefer this way to building url strings.

```
String searchFor = URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "utf-8");
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
    .authority("mysite")
    .appendPath("search.php")
    .appendQueryParameter("q", searchFor);
url = new URL(builder.build().toString());
```

---

And if you think encoding a `+` will mess something up, then see this

```
URLEncoder.encode("the+book", "utf-8"); // the%2Bbook
```

Answer (score 0):

as cricket_007 comment, try this code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try {
    String a = "";
    if(params != null && params.length > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            a += params[i];
            if(params.length > i+1){
            a += "%20";
         }
    }
 }

    url = new URL("mysite/search.php?q="+a);
```

Comment: And you would call that with `execute("the", "book)"` or `execute("The book".split(" "))`

Comment: And out of bounds exception at `params[i+1]`, probably

Comment: @Helpme The answer no longer has that line